# How do I reference a filename with spaces in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, filenames

I want to create an [external reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f) to cells in an Excel spreadsheet named `Employee Data.xls`.

When I enter the formula `=[Employee Data.xls]sheet1!A1`, I keep getting the error "*The name that you entered is not valid. The name contains a space or other invalid characters*".

[image: Error message]

I've tried a few different formulas, including:

- `=[Employee Data.xls]sheet1!A1`
- `=["Employee Data.xls"]sheet1!A1`
- `=[Employee%20Data.xls]sheet1!A1`
- `=[Employee\ Data.xls]sheet1!A1`

The only "solution" I've found is renaming the file to remove the spaces (i.e. `EmployeeData.xls`).

**How can I reference an external file in Excel if the filename contains spaces?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
='[Employee Data.xls]sheet1'!A1
```

Moreover, if the file is closed, you can add the path in the beginning, i.e.

```
='C:\My Folder\[Employee Data.xls]sheet1'!A1
```

p.s. Excel will add the path automatically if you close the file.

Comment: Is it possible to use a relative path for a closed file? (i.e. spreadsheet is in same folder as current file)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro if the file is closed you need full path, as in the last part I just added. p.s: Twin thinking :)